# JS returned value is undefined?

Tags: javascript, function, return, undefined

Im trying to return the value **itemIDsList** but it shows up in the console as undefined?

```
function getAllData() {
    fetch("JSONitemIDsList.json")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        var itemIDsList = data.ids
    })
    return itemIDsList

}
var itemIDsList = getAllData()
console.log(itemIDsList)
```

JSON file:

```
{
    "ids": [
        "sw0001a",
        "sw0001b",
         ....
         ...
         ..
         .
]}
```

Comment: You need to return itemIDsList from inside the then. Like
.then(data => {
   var itemIDsList = data.ids
  return itemIDsList
})

Comment: @Anil still not going to make any difference since it is asynchronous.

Comment: oh my bad... didn't see the function invoke
You might want to return a promise from getAllData and resolve it from then(). and 
call it like getAllData().then(data => {})
or can use aync-await